# twitter bootstrap: every button closes modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, alert

I'm using **bootstrap 2.3.0** to show a modal. In this modal, i show sometimes an alert, when an error occurs. But when the user clicks on the alert close button, the modal closes too. I'm not sure why? Both, the alert and the modal, have the css class `close`, but the value of the `data-dismiss` attribute of the alert targets to `alert` and the same attribute of the modal targets to `modal`. Although the modal closes at the same moment the alert appears.

Regards, Cid

EDIT:

Actually i have the problem, that every button i placed inside the modal, closes it whether the attribute `data-dismiss="modal"` is set or not.

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="dlg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="dlgLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
        I close the modal</button>
        <h3 id="dlgLabel">Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <button class="btn" id="btn">I close the modal too</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn pull-right" id="cancel" data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-hidden="true">I close the modal</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is responsible for the the the alert creation ? can we see some code or a jsfiddle ?

Comment: The alert is one like the following: `<div class="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>`.

Comment: Still not seeing the bug [on this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/qaSnX/). You should try to reproduce the bug yourself. You must be calling something yourself that closes the modal where you shouldn't.

Comment: Ok, i use bootstrap together with meteor an it's reactive data sources, which means: that the page will rendered again on data changes. At the click event from the alert-close-button, i delete the error message in the database. It could be, that this issues my modals. But this idea came too late. Meanwhile i removed the modals from my project and replaced them with other solutions.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a pure JavaScript modal. Cause: not defining the *type* attribute for each button in the modal. The type attribute can be either *button*, *reset* or *submit*. When no type is specified, it will default to *type="submit"*. Maybe that is what's closing your modal. Put a type attribute into EVERY button inside the modal and test it out. It solved the problem for me.